# Why image is not shrinking along with brower?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Here is my HTML Code:

```
  <div class="choice">

      <div class="choiceone">
          <a href="#two"><img src="images/choiceone.png" alt="titlef"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="choicetwo">
          <a href="#three"><img src="images/choicetwo.png" alt="titlev"></a>
     </div> 

  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .choice { 
     display: flex; 
     justify-content: space-around; 
     margin-top: 36%; 
     margin-bottom: 10%; 
     max-width: 100%; 
     height: auto; 
     position: static; }
```

The two choices are images as buttons, that when clicked, work as a jump link to another section of the page. I've inserted `max-width:100` and `height: auto`, even tried just `width:100%; height:auto`, and it still doesn't seem to work. The images do not move along with minimizing of the browser.

[Here is the published version of my site.](https://xarts.usfca.edu/~jyang67/rootfolder2/)

Looking at the published version above, you can see the two images do not move along with other elements in the page. How do I fix this?

Comment: could you post your css code here.

Comment: @DanielH 

.choice {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 36%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: static;

}

Answer (score 0):

In your `#one` remove the    `padding-top: 20%;` and change the height to `height: 100%;` and also change the position to `position: absolute;`

Also in your `.choice` class, remove the `margin-top: 26%;` and add the folowing :

```
top: 90%;
position: relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `height: 100%` and `width: auto`.

Also, why not put the `underline` into that two PNG (FRUITS / VEGGIES) so you don't have to match two img with position

```css
#one {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(../images/Backgroundgif.gif);
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Position background image of #one element to center

```css
#one {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(../images/Backgroundgif.gif);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
}
```